# Why does css background-image not work?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a menu with a background-image but according to the web console, the browser can't find the image. I have this problem for a very long time and until now I don't know how to fix it. I think the solution is very simple but I don't find it.

The image is in the right map because if I load the image in a img tag the browsers shows the image.
I run it local host and I use Firefox

see my code below.

Can somebody help with solving this problem?

```css
body{
 margin: 0px;
}
nav{
 position: fixed;
 top:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background-image: url('img/menu1.jpg');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/svg.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"/>
</head>
<body>
 <nav >
  <ul class="banner">
   <li>Test menu</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="menu">
  </ul>

 </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: probably background-image: url('../img/menu1.jpg'); will solve

Comment: What is the name of the image? Is it in the right folder? If you type the url of the image into the browser address bar, does it load?

Comment: Is your css and html file located in the same directory?

Comment: @dan I have a map for the site. there is the html file located and in that map I have a css map where of course the css file is located.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change your

```
background-image: url('img/menu1.jpg');
```

to

```
background-image: url('../img/menu1.jpg');
```

The path of your rule is relative to css file, not relative to html file.

Quote from [**Quick Reminder About File Paths**](http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)

> You have to pay attention to the relationship of where the file is
>   that is referencing the image, and where that image actually is.
>
> Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:
>
> - Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
> - Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
> - Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts there (and so on...)

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. But I find it strange because in the beginning it was not necessary to do that.

Comment: Thanks that reminder about file paths helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the image in your CSS file should be relative to THAT file, and not your HTML document